# Accessing test users only in test methods

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm writing a unit test with some testusers. I have an assert statement which checks some values on test users. The issue is that the testcase is also able to access production users which are messing up the test results. Is there a way to limit access to only testusers while running tests?

Comment: Add Id matching condition while fetching the users and use only those.

Comment: Sharing the test class would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm) describes, `User` is one of a small number of objects where instances are visible in unit tests. There is no way to change that behavior so you need to deal with it in your test code.

Krishna suggests one approach in his comment where you keep hold of the Id values of the Users you insert in your test and filter by those. Another approach is to add a distinct value to one of the fields of the Users you insert that again you use to filter.